# ui-grid datepicker not setting the value in angular js

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-grid

```
{
    "firstName": "Cox",
    "lastName": "Carney",
    "company": "Enormo",
    "test":{ "date": "10/14/2015 02:45:33 AM"}
 }
```

if I bind the date to the `ui-grid datepicker` and change the `datepicker` value of a row it is not reflecting in the grid.

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
        enableGridMenu: true,
        data: 'data',
        columnDefs: [
            { name: 'First Name', field: 'firstName' },
            { name: 'Last Name', field: 'lastName'},
            { name: 'Company', field: 'company' },
            { name: 'Date',
                field: 'test.date',
                cellFilter: 'textDate:"M/d/yyyy"',
                editableCellTemplate: '<div><form name="inputForm"><div ui-grid-edit-datepicker ng-class="\'colt\' + col.uid"></div></form></div>'
            }
        ],
        enableCellEditOnFocus: true
    };
```

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/tXuZyLA3YRUyOUUeVbul?p=preview is the sample plunker

Answer (score 0):

```
 {
              "firstName": "Cox",
              "lastName": "Carney",
              "company": "Enormo",
              "test":"10/14/2015 02:45:33 AM"
 }
```

Make it like this and then in `columnDefs:`

```
{ 
   name: 'Date',
   field: 'test',
   cellFilter: 'textDate:"M/d/yyyy"',
   editableCellTemplate: '<div><form name="inputForm"><div ui-grid-edit-datepicker ng-class="\'colt\' + col.uid"></div></form></div>'
}
```

Propably something is wrong with objects in `datepicker`.